# create-react-app-typescript: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I am building a react application using the tool create-react-app-typescript. I have been able to build 2 test applications by running the tool and following the instruction. Now suddenly when I run `npm start` I get this error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

But I have imported my types. Here is my node_modules/@types folder:
[image]

And this is the line that produces this error:

```
const logo = require('./logo.svg');
```

The compiler cannot resolve the `resolve` simple. I'll say it again: this was working until a couple of hours ago.

There might be something I am not doing regarding this tool `create-react-app-typescript`. Any help and any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue, and trying to nail down the exact "why". What I've found is if I downgrade typescript from 2.4.1 to 2.4.0, things go back to normal, so I believe it's a change in that patch that's causing issues with node types (and a few other types for us, e.g reselect).

Comment: @Ritwik. The issue has been fixed. Get the latest version from github and you should be ok to go